# How is the phonecat tutorial git repository setup to allow learners to step through the tutorial

Tags: angularjs, git, github

While going through the AngularJS phonecat tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00), I was very impressed the way the git repository is setup to allow the learner to checkout any particular step and look at diffs between that step and the previous/next step.

I started thinking about how the Git repository would be setup to achieve this.
Initially while creating the tutorial if each step was performed and checked-in and tagged then the repository would allow each step to be checkout and compared against other steps, easy. However, this quickly falls apart when you think the tutorial needs to be kept up-to-date without effecting the diffs between steps and also updating all the steps to use newer code or libraries.

Can some git ninja explain to me how they have achieved this. I see several branches and many check-ins to update to new version in their repo (https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat). But the updates do not effect the learners view of the steps and the diffs between them. How?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the tutorial make use of tags to mark the commits in the project, you can type `git tag`and you will see a list of steps from step-0 to step-12.

you can make use of tags to mark your commits by using `git tag [tag name]` in your current working directory and the tag will point to your current commits.
Hope my explaination is clear enough that you can make use of it.

Btw The phonecat tutorial is really good.